# postgres ip address on auth logs

Tags: postgresql

I am looking how to strong security on my Postgres database implementing fail2ban

But checking on logs i can't see the ip adress of failed connection

```
2020-03-30 11:19:50.929 CEST [21167] postgres@test_ecofil FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2020-03-30 11:19:50.929 CEST [21167] postgres@test_ecofil DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
```

checking for something  like this

```
Mar 30 11:29:19 xxxx sshd[13605]: Invalid user xxxxx from xx.xxx.xx.x
```

There is a way to do that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `%h` to `log_line_prefix` parameter (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LINE-PREFIX): it should display the host name or IP address.

Comment: thanks. problem solved

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on `log_connections`, it will log the IP address of attempted connections, independently of `log_line_prefix` also doing so.

If you control that your passwords are actually good ones, then fail2ban adds essentially no additional security.